# XML formatting comparison

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have a strange issue with XML formatting.

Is

```xml
<SomeObject Name="SomeName" Surname="Surname" Age="23" />
```

the same as:

```xml
<SomeObject>
    <Name>SomeName</Name>
    <Surname>Surname</Surname>
    <Age>23</Age>
</SomeObject>
```

Could you check and tell me if those two markups mean the same?

Comment: What tools and/or language are you using for parsing/writing this?

Comment: what do you mean by the same? syntax level or conceptual level?

Comment: It's some kind of a SOAP request header. Already solved by @Michael Kay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your snippets uses an element with attributes, the other uses an element with child elements. That's not a formatting difference, it's a different way of modelling your data.

What exactly is your question? If you're asking whether these two snippets are the same, then the answer is no, they aren't.

Comment: I want to ask if both snippets mean the same.

Comment: depends on the functionality if the xml-consuming part. The key question is, what you mean by "mean the same". Xml-wise and therefore technically they differ from other as Michael stated correctly

Comment: The "meaning" of an XML document is something known only to its users. For example (to be slightly perverse) you might have a convention that verified information goes in child elements and unverified information goes in attributes. If that's your convention, then these two snippets don't have the same meaning. In other words, we can't know whether these two snippets have the same meaning unless you share the information enabling us to read the XML and extract meaning from it.

Comment: @MichaelKay That's the thing I was looking for. The difference you mentioned by "One of your snippets uses an element with attributes, the other uses an element with child elements." Here was the error in my soap request. It had to be an element with attributes but I had been creating the element with child elements. Thanks a lot.